# why isnt the following loop iterating as expected

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Im trying to write a test function using pytest and selenium that tests the Nav bar links, the loop will iterate twice then I get the following error

> "FAILED tests/test_system.py::test_menu -
> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

the code is as follows:

Pytest:

```
def test_menu(driver):
    driver.get("http://localhost:3000/enter_invoice")
    title_name = ["Orders","Enter Invoice","Stock"]
    i=0
    navbar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'navbar-nav')
    links = navbar.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
    for link in links:
        print("Test",link)
        link.click()
        #title=driver.title
        #assert title == title_name[i]
        time.sleep(3)
        i=i+1
    time.sleep(3)
```

Menu HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://dkit.ie" id="dkit_menu">DKiT</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/get_orders" id="get_orders_menu">Orders</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/enter_invoice" id="enter_invoice_menu">Add Invoice</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/item_list" id="stock_list_menu">Show Stock</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I've tried checking to make sure im assigning the elements correctly within the nav var in pytest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If clicking on a link takes you to a new page, then you will get this error, because the next link refers to an element that is not part of the current (new) page.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the link does take you to a new page which also uses the same menu layout as above, all three pages do use the same menu not sure why it works on the first two run throughs but not the third

Comment: Perhaps the first two links refer to different locations within the same page, and so a new page is not loaded for those.

Comment: You were correct I managed to get the code working by manually clicking through the link asserting the page title going back to the source page then running through each part manually. Thank you for the help.